# PayPal Adaptive Payments, Working with redirects

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

We're trying to integrate PayPal Adaptive Payments,

This is how our form looks like:

```
     <form class="standard" action="/our-controller" method="post" target="PPDGFrame"> 
            <input type="image" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_checkout_pp_142x27.png">
            <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="mini">
            </form>

            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
              var embeddedPPFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlowmini({trigger: 'submitBtn'});
            </script>
```

As you can see we are not providing `payKey` the reason for that we don't want to make `API calls` on each page view so we are trying to first redirect to our controller where `payKey` is fetched and redirect to the actual `PayPal checkout page`.

But we are getting this constantly:
`To help protect your account, we logged you out. Click the refresh button in your browser window to log in again and start your transaction over.`

Is there any way to achieve our goals? Because if we are providing `payKey` in input, it works find, but not with our workflow.